# Executing a StoredProcedure in Dotnetcore3.1

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core

I created a `Stored Procedure` by `Select`ing values from 2 different tables.

Now the problem I have is to execute and read the result data from my `dotnetcore 3.1` code.

1. I am not sure if the code I have written is correct. I am using `IQueryable<AppUser>` but, The SP contains a mix of AppUser and `CourseMarks`. So can I represent the result ?
2. How to convert the result of `IQueryable` to a JSON format ?

Can someone please help me out sort this. I have been stuck in this issue for awhile now.

```
        var userId= new SqlParameter("@UserId",2);

        IQueryable<AppUser> userType =  _dbContext.AppUsers.FromSqlRaw("exec dbo.GetCourseAndCourseMark @UserId", userId).IgnoreQueryFilters();
```

**SQL - SP**

```
SELECT U.[Name],CM.CourseName , CM.CourseResult 
       U.ID,
       ISNULL(SUM(CM.Marks),0) AS TotalMarks
FROM dbo.[AppUser] U 
     LEFT JOIN dbo.CourseMarks CM ON U.ID = CM.UserID
WHERE U.ID = @UserId
GROUP BY U.[Name],
         U.ID, CM.CourseName , CM.CourseResult ;
```

Comment: Read about Keyless Entity Types https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: This is a SP, so in that case I will have to pass a parameter `UserId`. Keyless entity types are talking about creating a view or table. In that case will I be able to update `UserId` ? Sorry if this is a bad question. I am newbie in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a special class for your sp result, it should include ALL data properties that are selected in your sp

```
[NotMapped]
public class SpResult
{
     public int ID  {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public double TotalMarks {get; set;}

      .... and so on
}
```

All properties in this class should be the same name and type as it is in your stored procedure

Add SpPlayerResult to db context and run this code

```
public virtual DbSet<SpResult> SpResults { get; set; }

....      
var userId= new SqlParameter("@UserId",2);

var userType =  _dbContext.SpResults.FromSqlRaw("exec dbo.GetCourseAndCourseMark @UserId", userId)
.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't know why you need convert it to json, since .net will do everything automatically, but you can use standard net serializer System.Text.Json

```
var json=  JsonSerializer.Serialize(userType);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I spent 1 whole day trying to figure this out.